# Lenovo B570 Ubuntu 13.04 wireless connectivity issues

Tags: wireless, 13.04, lenovo

I have just recently performed a clean-install of Ubuntu on my Lenovo B570 and now I cannot connect to any wireless networks. I can see the list of networks, but I am unable to successfully connect. I have tried the available fix that worked for Ubuntu 11-12, but it just doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: It seems to be working now after enabling restricted drivers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to askubuntu! Please consider adding the solution you've reached as an **answer** (to your own question), so others with the same problem may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

In your wireless network settings you need to add your wireless **IP** and **DNS**.